# Deploy Meteor js App on Centos 7

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, centos7, npm-install

I have been on this since yesterday. i am following this tutorial. Even though, it is for Ubuntu installation I was able to find away around it the installation process on Cent OS. when issued the command `npm install` I kept getting this error. This has been since yesterday I have been on this deployment process. This is the tutorial - [https://vpsineu.com/blog/how-to-install-nginx-mongodb-nodejs-and-host-meteorjs-applications-on-an-ubuntu-vps/][1]. I am getting this error:

```
[meteor@christdoes server]$ npm install

> fibers@1.0.15 install /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-48` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js


> bson@0.2.21 install /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
make: Leaving directory `/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'

> kerberos@0.0.9 install /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
make: Leaving directory `/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gridfs-stream@0.5.3 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/gridfs-stream
mongodb@1.4.35 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb
bson@0.2.21 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
nan@1.7.0 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/node_modules/nan
kerberos@0.0.9 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
nan@1.6.2 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/node_modules/nan
readable-stream@1.0.33 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/readable-stream
core-util-is@1.0.1 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/core-util-is
isarray@0.0.1 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/isarray
string_decoder@0.10.31 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/string_decoder
inherits@2.0.1 /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/inherits

> bcrypt@1.0.2 install /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[bcrypt] Success: "/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-042stab123.3
npm ERR! argv "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/npm" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-debug.log

npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-042stab123.3
npm ERR! argv "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/opt/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script 'node npm-rebuild.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node npm-rebuild.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/meteor/webapps/schoolapps/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
[meteor@christdoes server]$ ^C
[meteor@christdoes server]$
```

Comment: `node v6.11.1` is not the version meteor requires. Check in your development project via `meteor --version` and install this version on your cent OS. If then `npm install`
 still throws errors please extend your post.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use MeteorUp to deploy your meteor application on a server: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up

To make it work on CentOs you just need to install Docker manually on the server and mup do the rest.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks. I'm inexperienced in using docker. Any doc to this effect?

Comment: Just follow the readme and you don’t need to know docker to make your application work. Deploying is as easy as « mup deploy ».

Comment: What's to be specified as the ```ROOT_URL```?