# Meteor app deployment using MeteorUp tool

Tags: meteor, deployment, windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, meteor-up

My appreciation goes to @fnkrm and @Jankapunkt from this [Deploy Meteor js App on Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103181/deploy-meteor-js-app-on-centos-7?noredirect=1#comment79198797_46103181) earlier thread who pointed me to this Meteor deployment tool. I'm using meteor up for deployment. I believe this is best deployment tool I have ever used.

After setting up the config as requested in the docs, this is the config I arrived at

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx',
      username: 'root',
      // pem: './path/to/pem'
       password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'mpapps',
    path: '../myapps',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'http://xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor',
    },

    // ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
    //   autogenerate: {
    //     email: 'email.address@domain.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
    //     domains: 'website.com,www.website.com'
    //   }
    // },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is using Meteor 1.3 or older
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

This is the error log I got on the server when I ran `mup.cmd setup`

```
[103.219.22.54] - Start Mongo
[103.219.22.54] x Start Mongo: FAILED

        -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
        Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
        Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to point your mongo to localhost. As far I know, Meteor up deploy to your server two dockers containers (if you have just one server), one for your meteor application and one for your DB, normally called mongodb (you can have more like UAT and LIVE per ex).

You can as well check out the official web site docs here [Meteor Up Example Configs](http://meteor-up.com/docs.html#example-configs)

You can try to point your env -> MONGO_URL to the correct container, like so:

**MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb:3001/YOUR_APP_NAME'** instead of:

**MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor'**

Make sure as well the ports that we are deploying.

OBS: *I don't know if you changed the app name and path to post here, but check that out too.*

Answer (score 0):

Mongo runs on port 27017 by default, but you are using 3001.

I think if you change that, it should all work.

```
MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor',
```

For safety I would add

`port: 27017,`

to the mongo config